# Apache Zeppelin with Spark Interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am currently exploring Zeppelin with Spark interpreter. Have a question?

Once i query all the required data using Spark interpreter where does it store for further action like group by, drill down etc. For every action does it except the spark job.

Comment: You question is not very clear. Zeppelin actually acts a little like a Spark-Shell

Answer (score 0):

The computation and storage of data is handled by Spark itself, refer to spark execution model for more details.
Link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#performance-impact